# How do I only return the data I need using GraphQL?

Tags: database, server, graphql, backend

I am excited to start using GraphQL instead of REST but I still can't figure out how I would only return the data I need from a database without returning all the data every time.

Example:
I query the database for a user object that has 10 fields, I use graphql to return the entire object. Not a problem! But then I want to query that user object again using graphql but only return just one field. I know graphql can filter the data back out to the client but I would still need to query the database for the entire object.

Is there any way to make it only return back one field without having to return back the entire object?

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on the Database you are using. If you are using mongodb it wouldn't bennefit using aggregate for this purpuse since those are heavy for db and is almost certainly it would be better to retrieve the full obj from the db and then let graphql filter what's needed by the client.

Also remember that GraphQL is intended to send the client only what's needed but it doesn't manage how you retrieve the information (it could be from a database, memory, static content, etc..)